# Meteor check if the findOne result has property

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
while(parentId){
    ancestors.push(parentId);
    parent = Comments.findOne(parentId);
    if(typeof parent.parentCommentId === "undefined"){
      break;
    } else {
      parentId = parent.parentCommentId;
      console.log(parentId);
    }
}
```

I want this code to push all parentCommentId in a array until top.But the top comment document do not has field parentCommentId.

And I have this error in console

`Cannot read property 'parentCommentId' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'parentCommentId' of undefined"}`

The typeof and hasOwnProperty not work,How can I check the property

Comment: Use a callback function to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'parentCommentId' of undefined

This means the object that owns the property you are trying to access is undefined, so the problem is not with the property.

In your case, it seems `Comments.findOne` didn't find anything with that id, so the `parent` object is undefined.

Just so you know, another way to check for the presence of a property in an object is just:

```
if (parent.parentCommentId) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments.findOne(parentId) can return undefined if there is no result with given ID.

```
parent = Comments.findOne(parentId); //parent can be undefined
if (!parent) {
    //parent is undefined
} else {
    //parent found
}
```

The code above is the same as:

```
parent = Comments.findOne(parentId); //parent can be undefined
if (typeof parent === "undefined"){
    //parent is undefined
} else {
    //parent found
}
```

So the answer is: You need to check if parent is defined. If yes, then you can access its properties.